# android manifest parsing/reading from a java program

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I need to read android manifest file and copy some values from it like launcher activity, package name, path of activity etc in a java program. which is the best way to do this

Answer (score 2):

I use following code to read version number from the AndroidManifest.xml

```
PackageInfo pinfo = null;
try
{
     pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(),0);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

you can read the version info in  as follows,

```
String version = pinfo.versionName;
```

same way you can user other properties

Comment: I am not working in an android project. I am working on a java project where i need to use the android manifest.